Struggling with Left Joins in MS Access
I'm running into an issue with MS Access as I'm not all that familiar with Access SQL.
My Left Joins are being treated as inner joins due to Access placing the criteria of the left joins outside of the join clause. I've reviewed a few other topics here and haven't found a suggestion that solves my issue. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!
The original query that Access Visual Designer outputs:
SELECT DISTINCT 
SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID,
SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, 
STUDENT_TYPE.STUDENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, 
SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Opportunity_Offered, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Lottery_Offered, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS FSEOG_Offered, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Pell_Offered
FROM ((((SATURN_SPRIDEN INNER JOIN (SATURN_SGBSTDN INNER JOIN STUDENT_TYPE ON SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_STYP_CODE = STUDENT_TYPE.STUDENT_TYPE_CODE) ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM) 
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_PIDM) 
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1 ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_PIDM) 
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2 ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_PIDM) 
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3 ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_PIDM
WHERE (((SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF)=[entry term]) AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE)=[aidy]) AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE) In ('SNMOS','SNMOSG','SNMOSR','SNMOSF')) AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE)=[aidy]) AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE)='SLOTT') AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE)=[aidy]) AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE)='FSEOG') AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE)=[aidy]) AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE)='FPELL'));

How I would design this in Oracle SQL for my desired outcome:
SELECT DISTINCT 
    SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID,
    SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
    SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, 
    STUDENT_TYPE.STUDENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, 
    SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF, 
    FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Opportunity_Offered, 
    FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Lottery_Offered, 
    FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS FSEOG_Offered, 
    FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Pell_Offered
FROM 
    SATURN_SPRIDEN
    INNER JOIN SATURN_SGBSTDN 
        ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM
    INNER JOIN STUDENT_TYPE 
        ON SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_STYP_CODE = STUDENT_TYPE.STUDENT_TYPE_CODE
    LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD 
        ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE IN ('SNMOS', 'SNMOSG', 'SNMOSR', 'SNMOSF')
    LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1 
        ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE = 'SLOTT'
    LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2 
        ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE = 'FSEOG'
    LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3 
        ON SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
        AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE = 'FPELL'
WHERE 
    SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = [entry term];

Updating to add, I tried the below suggestion per @jarlh and my access db crashes rather than erroring:
    SELECT DISTINCT 
SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_ID,
SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_LAST_NAME, 
SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_FIRST_NAME, 
STUDENT_TYPE.STUDENT_TYPE_DESCRIPTION, 
SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Opportunity_Offered, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Lottery_Offered, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS FSEOG_Offered, 
FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_OFFER_AMT AS Pell_Offered
FROM (((((( SATURN_SPRIDEN 
INNER JOIN SATURN_SGBSTDN ON (SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_PIDM))
INNER JOIN STUDENT_TYPE ON (SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_STYP_CODE = STUDENT_TYPE.STUDENT_TYPE_CODE)) 
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD ON (SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_PIDM AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE=[aidy] AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE In ('SNMOS','SNMOSG','SNMOSR','SNMOSF'))) 
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1 ON (SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_PIDM AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE=[aidy] AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_1.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE='SLOTT'))
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2 ON (SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_PIDM AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE=[aidy] AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_2.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE ='FSEOG'))
LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3 ON (SATURN_SPRIDEN.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_PIDM AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE=[aidy] AND FAISMGR_RPRAWRD_3.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE='FPELL'))
WHERE ((SATURN_SGBSTDN.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF)=[entry term]) AND ((FAISMGR_RPRAWRD.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE)=[aidy]);



Move all LEFT JOIN tables' conditions from WHERE to ON.

This looks like one common join and the other flavours of it achieved with where clauses.  As jarlh has said add these to the ON ='s and is there anything wrong with the result?

That Oracle query only needs a couple of extra parentheses to work in Access (one right after the FROM for each join, and one after each join)

Some of those WHERE criteria are not field links, but static parameters. How can those be in ON clause? I have never seen that. Could this need subqueries?

Static parameters can be in an ON clause just fine, as long as you use sufficient parentheses (might need them around all comparisons in the ON). It can't be represented in the query builder, but so can't greater than, less than and lots of other JOINs

Where does [aidy] come from? Use shorter but meaningful table aliases, it would make the queries easier to read.

my access db crashes Does it actually crash, or does it freeze because the query is taking very long? -- Where is your data actually stored? Local Access tables / Linked Access tables / Linked ODBC tables?

Ms-Access SQL can be a bit fussy about the parenhesis; try this:
SELECT 
* 
FROM 
  (
    (
      (
        (
          (
            SATURN_SPRIDEN AS SPR 
            INNER JOIN SATURN_SGBSTDN AS SGBS 
            ON SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SGBS.SGBSTDN_PIDM
          ) 
          INNER JOIN STUDENT_TYPE AS STYP 
          ON SGBS.SGBSTDN_STYP_CODE = STYP.STUDENT_TYPE_CODE
        ) 
        LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR0 
        ON (SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR0.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
            AND FR0.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
            AND FR0.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE in ('SNMOS', 'SNMOSG','SNMOSR','SNMOSF'))
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR1 
      ON (SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR1.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
          AND FR1.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
          AND FR1.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE= 'SLOTT')
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR2 
    ON (SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR2.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
        AND FR2.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
        AND FR2.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE= 'FSEOG')
  ) 
  LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR3 
  ON (SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR3.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
      AND FR3.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] 
      AND FR3.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE= 'FPELL') 
WHERE 
   SGBS.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF= [entry_term];

This can't be represented graphically (i.e. switching to design view breaks the query with a warning).
The following (not tested) can be represented graphically:
SELECT 
*
FROM 
  (
    (
      (
        (
          (
            SATURN_SPRIDEN AS SPR 
            INNER JOIN SATURN_SGBSTDN AS SGBS 
            ON SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = SGBS.SGBSTDN_PIDM
          ) 
          INNER JOIN STUDENT_TYPE AS STYP 
          ON SGBS.SGBSTDN_STYP_CODE = STYP.STUDENT_TYPE_CODE
        ) 
        LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR0 
        ON SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR0.RPRAWRD_PIDM
      ) 
      LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR1 
      ON SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR1.RPRAWRD_PIDM
    ) 
    LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR2 
    ON SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR2.RPRAWRD_PIDM
  )
  LEFT JOIN FAISMGR_RPRAWRD AS FR3 
  ON SPR.SPRIDEN_PIDM = FR3.RPRAWRD_PIDM 
WHERE 
   SGBS.SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF= [entry_term]
 AND (FR0.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE is null OR (FR0.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] AND FR0.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE in ('SNMOS', 'SNMOSG','SNMOSR','SNMOSF')))
 AND (FR1.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE is null OR (FR1.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] AND FR1.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE= 'SLOTT'))
 AND (FR2.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE is null OR (FR2.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] AND FR2.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE= 'FSEOG'))
 AND (FR3.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE is null OR (FR3.RPRAWRD_AIDY_CODE = [aidy] AND FR3.RPRAWRD_FUND_CODE= 'FPELL'))
;

You will need to replace the SELECT ... part for your requirement (I didn't create all of your columns in my test)

I would agree with this answer, but I would also point out that when I have used SQL formatters/beautifiers in visual studio code that MS access will complain about the new lines before and after some of the parentheses. I mention this if you still have trouble.

@tinazmu
I greatly appreciate the detailed response! These queries now compile error-free, but I am running into a crashing issue with Access that I will work to resolve with my IT Team. Thanks a bunch.
